# Using look-up table to replace factor values

Tags: r

I am looking for more efficient version of my code that would replace the factors in a dataframe.

Here's my dataset:

```
structure(list(Rio.Olympics.Sports.Participating.Team = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("American Gymnastics", 
"American Swimmers", "Boxing", "European Gymnastics", "Running", 
"Free-style swimming", "Breaststroke Swimming", "Diving", "Athletics", 
"Soccer"), class = "factor"), Calendar.Quarter = structure(c(16071, 
16161, 16252, 16344, 16436, 16526, 16617, 16709, 16801, 16892, 
16983, 17075, 16071, 16161, 16252, 16344, 16436, 16526, 16617, 
16709, 16801, 16892, 16983, 17075, 16071, 16161, 16252, 16344, 
16436, 16526, 16617, 16709, 16801, 16892, 16983, 17075, 16071, 
16161, 16252, 16344, 16436, 16526, 16617, 16709, 16801, 16892, 
16983, 17075, 16071, 16161, 16252, 16344, 16436, 16526, 16617, 
16709, 16801, 16892, 16983, 17075), class = "Date"), Randomized.Viewers = c(49, 
45, 51, 55, 47, 48, 54, 57, 53, 50, 52, 58, 32, 29, 33, 40, 34, 
36, 31, 39, 37, 30, 35, 41, 5, 1, 25, 46, 38, 4, 56, 27, 21, 
43, 42, 44, 2, 59, 3, 10, 60, 7, 14, 24, 13, 16, 17, 28, 15, 
6, 19, 23, 11, 12, 20, 22, 9, 8, 18, 26)), .Names = c("Rio.Olympics.Sports.Participating.Team", 
"Calendar.Quarter", "Randomized.Viewers"), row.names = c(NA, 
-60L), class = "data.frame")
```

Now, I want to change the factor labels. Here's what I did:

```
Old_labels <- c("American Swimmers", "American Gymnastics", 
               "European Gymnastics", "Running", "Boxing")
New_labels <- c("Jupitean Swimmers", "Saturnish Gymastics", 
               "Plutoish Gymnastics", "Walking", "Fighting")
Apply_lables <- data.frame(Old_labels, New_labels)
colnames(Apply_lables)[1] <- "Old_labels"
```

Finally, this code would do the trick:

```
p1 <- p
p1$Rio.Olympics.Sports.Participating.Team <- 
  Apply_lables[match(p$Rio.Olympics.Sports.Participating.Team, 
                     Apply_lables$Old_labels), "New_labels"]
```

Here's the modified dataframe:

```
 Rio.Olympics.Sports.Participating.Team Calendar.Quarter Randomized.Viewers
1                      Jupitean Swimmers       2014-01-01                 49
2                      Jupitean Swimmers       2014-04-01                 45
3                      Jupitean Swimmers       2014-07-01                 51
4                      Jupitean Swimmers       2014-10-01                 55
5                      Jupitean Swimmers       2015-01-01                 47
6                      Jupitean Swimmers       2015-04-01                 48
```

**Question:** As a beginner in R, I struggled a lot for a few hours. Although I managed to get what I want, is there any better way (i.e. fewer lines of code and faster implementation) to change factors based on look-up table? My original dataset has about 1M rows, and above code takes a lot of time to run.

I did research this topic on SO, but I don't think this was covered anywhere. Although there were a few posts that talked about using match() to use look-up table to change rows.

Comment: Check out the new `forcats` package that hit CRAN this week.

Comment: Or just use `levels(df$var)[match(Old_labels, levels(df$var) )] <- New_labels` and avoid adding a whole new dependency.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace `Old_labels` from a specific list, I presume you could just subset your `levels()` for the desired factor and push new labels there:

```
levels(dta$Rio.Olympics.Sports.Participating.Team)[
    dta$Rio.Olympics.Sports.Participating.Team %in% Old_labels] <-
    New_labels
```